# React Form Hook: make selectors equal width again

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, demo

Here's a [link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-route-mui-3oer3) of this form I'm trying to make Using React form hooks and material ui. Code is inside `CreateEmployee.tsx` file under `components\execute` folder. UI Screenshot is below.

I'm trying to make:

1. The selector (background color: aqua) for gender and Designation be
   equal width.
2. The Submit button a bit larger, with more prominent
       font.

But I'm unable to do so with my limited css knowledge. Can someone please help?

[image: Form Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can make `select` elements to be same width:

```
select[name="Gender"],
select[name="Designation"] {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

Here is how to make 50% split in rows with `select` elements:

```
.form-label-group label {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Submit button:

```
input[type=submit] {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

In regards to submit button, it's better to add `className="anythingyouwant"` to button element and change (in css) `input[type=submit]` to `.anythingyouwant`

Comment: Will add styles for button shortely

Comment: Thank you! The min-width part works great. Any ideas on how to increase the height of the submit button? Things like `height: 200px` don't work

Comment: Can you check again because `height: 200px;` should work. Just be sure you are applying this style to button, not to `div#submit-button`

Comment: Yeah, only when i add a background color, does the submit button change its appearance, otherwise, it doesn't change at all!

Comment: Idk, changing height works for me. Anyway, checkout buttons you already have available in your app: [Button]( https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/). Using `Button` component  will save you from writting your own css